# Gnome on Ubuntu 14.04 crashes after starting Progress DB

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, gnome

I am a Progress 4GL application developer. I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04. I'm using gnome and never had this problem before. Now whenever I start a progress db using my terminal (didn't try any other method) then the gnome UI crashes and logs me out. 
When I log back again then all the open windows are gone (quite logical) and the DB's are running.
So I just have get a terminal to start working again but this is very frustrating.
I'm using Ubuntu on Macbook Pro via Oracle Virtualbox VM.
Any fixes/suggestion are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely processor overload. Oracle VB Has troubles like this because you're running two operating systems at the *same time*. it all depends on your specs, if I could get those. Running two OSes at the same time on a (no offense, if applies) crap computer can make the VM crash like a drunk driver. You might just need to actually install Ubuntu on the computer as a real OS. That or install the KDE Version of Ubuntu. It looks and may work better anyway. No new programs needed.

Comment: Probably not, I just upgraded to 14.04 from 12.04 rest all specs are same. The crash started happening after the upgrade only.

Comment: No no no no, not what I meant, I meant the specs of your _computer_ not Ubuntu, stuff like how much RAM You have, how much ram you let ubuntu have, how much processor you have, how much processor you let ubuntu have, etc.

Comment: Before upgrade i had allocated 2.5 G RAM (Total 8) and 2 processors  (Total 4) to my VM running Ubuntu 12.04. AFter the upgrade everything is still same.

Comment: How many Ghz is that for the processors?

Comment: 2.9 Ghz processor

Comment: Huh. Probably a problem with the GNOME UI just not being able to handle it. Try an update to KDE Ubuntu. I use it and tried db and it worked.

Comment: Do you mean use the KDE desktop or upgrade the OS to KDE Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not sure you can just "use" the KDE straight from GNOME, but if you can, sure! If you can't, go ahead and upgrade.